# Tabbing with automatic line breaks

Tags: lists, enumitem, tabbing

I want to format text like this:

```
a) Bla bla bla bla lbal bla
   blablalakasdfdl sdlf sdfl
   blablalbalasldkfsdflksdf

b) b;sdfdfgldfgajs;dflsfsldfk
   s;dlfskfwopwerkrotkdfpgodfg
   osdofkdfgk fdogdfogk dofgk
```

I learned several ways to almost get what I want:

#### Using the tabbing environment

```
\begin{tabbing}
a) \= \\ \> blablabla dlgkdjfgd fklgjdfglkdfgj dflkgjdfg
dfjgldfgk jdflkgjdflgk jdfglkdjfglkdfjgldkfgjdfgkdlfkgjldfg
\end{tabbing}
```

The problem of the tabbing environment is that I need to putt `\\` where I want to have line breaks. Otherwise the whole text inside the tabbing environment is put on just one line.

#### Using the itemize environment

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[a) ] sadfsdf sdfsdf ... long text ...
\end{itemize}
```

It almost works perfectly except that everything inside the itemize environment is extra indented, e.g.

```
  a) Bla bla bla bla lbal bla
     blablalakasdfdl sdlf sdfl
     blablalbalasldkfsdflksdf

  b) b;sdfdfgldfgajs;dflsfsldfk
     s;dlfskfwopwerkrotkdfpgodfg
     osdofkdfgk fdogdfogk dofgk

Normal text that is not inside an itemize environment
```

So what is the best way to achieve what I desire?

Comment: Let me see if I have this straight: would a satisfactory answer be to remove the excess left-margin from the itemize environment?

Comment: @andrew Yes this is the answer (also the answer I marked as correct)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a list and adapt it e.g. with enumitem

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*),align=left]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow that's fast and exactly answers my question. Especially the `align=left` option