# How to enforce newlines in latex

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I am creating a macro driven songbook in LaTeX, and have run into a problem:
Linebreaks. I want the input text:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

To output like that in the PDF as well.
It is not an option to use `\\` or similar linebreaks, the point fo the macro is that people
should be able to just write in the text, and TeX should put it in as it's written.

Is there a way to make LaTeX respect the newlines?
I have found out how to parse double line breaks, using the following code:

```
\setlength\parskip{1em}                                                          
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                                                      
\def\arraystretch{2}
```

That will create vertical distance when using double linebreaks (starting new paragraphs).

Comment: You can take a look at how "verbatim" implements this. It uses "\par" (not entered by the user, but by the macro), as explained in page 7 of [this document](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/required/tools/verbatim.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I need other environments inside the texts, such as \multicoloumn. Verbatim would overrule those things.

Comment: Is there a way to make obey lines work when a new environment is started? If i within the \begingroup have a {\em bla bla} in it, but obeylines does not effect the {\em} scope.

Comment: {\em \begingroup\obeylines Text text
text \endgroup} wont work either.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. For the specific problem you should consider the `verse` environment.

Comment: You can create an environment and inside it issue `\obeylines`. See [Tabbing and automatic line breaks without columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104170/5764), which is most likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by egreg in the comments the `verse` environment did wonders for me :)
It also lead me to the `songs` package which is quite handy.